# What is Time complexity of "set" and "if item in array" in Python?

Tags: python, set, time-complexity, nested-loops, iterated-logarithm

I need to check if a number and its double exist in an array. This code using `set` to solve it. However I am not sure the Time complexity is better than `O(N^2)`. I use the `for loop` and `if 2*item in s` like below. Isn't it to know whether the item is in an array, we use another `O(N)`. Which mean `O(N^2)` in total? If it is optimal, how can I implement the codes in C without using `nested loop`?
Thanks a lot!

```
  def checkIfExist(arr]) -> bool:
    s = set(array)
    for item in s:
        if 2 * item in s and item != 0:
            return True
    if arr.count(0) >= 2:
        return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time complexity of the 'in' operator for sets in python is on average O(1) and only in the worst case O(N), since sets in python use a HashTable internally.

So your function's time complexity on average should be O(N) and only in the worst case will be O(N^2), where N is the length of the array.

More here https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity